# Weird PHP Regex Preg_Match Bug?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My PHP version is `PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7 (cli)`. However it looks like this problem occurs with all versions I've tested.

I've encountered a very weird bug when using preg_match. Anyone know a fix?

The first section of code here works, the second one doesn't. But the regex itself is valid. For some reason the `something_happened` word is causing it to fail.

```
$one = ' (branch|leaf)';
echo "ONE:\n";
preg_match('/(?:\( ?)?((?:(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)+(?: ?\| ?(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)+)(?: ?\))?/', $one, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches); // this works

$two = 'something_happened (branch|leaf)';
echo "\nTWO:\n";
preg_match('/(?:\( ?)?((?:(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)+(?: ?\| ?(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)+)(?: ?\))?/', $two, $matches2, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches2); // this doesn't work
```

It seems somehow related to the word `something_happened`. If I change this word it works.

The regex is matching 2 or more type names separated by `|` that may or may not be surrounded in `()`, and each type name may or may not be preceded by any number of `[]` (or `[some number]` or `[!some number]`) and `*`.

Try it and see for yourself! Please let me know if you know how to fix it!

Comment: Trying it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) gives me an error of "catastrophic backtracking" for the second example. Running the code from the question on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/GEgoO) coincides with your assertment - there are no matches for the second case. *However*, running it locally gives me a match. I'm baffled.

Comment: As for the case where you say _"It seems somehow related to the word something_happened. If I change this word it works."_ - it seems that length affects it (see [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/jILtl)), which makes sense considering the backtracking mentioned by the regex engine on the Regex101 site.

Comment: Please check [this fix](https://regex101.com/r/90zpXG/1), does it work as intended?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes looks like it correctly matches! What did you change? Want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `(?:(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)+` group: the `+` quantifier quantifies a group with many subsequent optional patterns, and that creates too many options to match a string before the subsequent patterns.

In PHP, you can workaround the problem by using either

1. Possessive quantifier:

```php
'/(?:\(\ ?)?((?:(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)++(?:\ ?\|\ ?(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)+)(?:\ ?\))?/'
```

Note the `++` at the end of the group mentioned.
2. Atomic group:

```php
'/(?:\(\ ?)?((?>(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)+(?:\ ?\|\ ?(?:\**\[(?:!?\d+)?\])*\**[A-Za-z_]\w*)+)(?:\ ?\))?/'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/90zpXG/3/). Note the `(?>...)` syntax.

Also, note how the regex is formatted [here](https://regex101.com/r/90zpXG/1), it is very convenient to use the `x` (extended) flag to break the regex into several lines, format it, so that it could be easier to track down the issue. It is required to escape all literal whitespace and `#` chars, but it is a minor inconvenience when it comes to debugging long patterns like this.

Comment: Amazing! Question: can I just use `?>` everywhere I previously used `?:`? Why would I want it to backtrack?

Comment: @Alasdair It depends on whether you want to re-match the patterns in the group upon match failure or not. You cannot blindly use possessive quantifiers or atomic groups.